# Any way to guarantee X amount of a specific number while generating random numbers in a 2D array

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I need to fill up a 2D array of size `n` with random numbers, however I need about `n(n-1)/2 * .2` or `.4` or `.8` of the generated random numbers to be `-1` and I need them spread out. Is there any possible way to do this? I thought about while filling up the array every so often make it set that element as `-1` and use a count to keep track however there is no way to be sure those `-1` are spread apart across the array, is this possible?

Comment: Maybe just generate `X` indices in the beginning (with checks for dupes) and set those to -1, and then go through and set each slot to be a random number if it isn't -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I can think of to do this would be:

- fill out the start of your array with the required amount of `-1`s
- fill out the rest of the array with random numbers
- shuffle the array, possibly using `std::random_shuffle` or something similar.

After doing this, you can be sure that you have the correct amount of `-1`s, and that they will be randomly distributed.

Comment: It should do. If it is just a normal 2d array you can do `std::random_shuffle(&array[0][0], &array[0][0]+width*height)` or `std::random_shuffle(&array[0][0], &array[width-1][height-1])` . If you want your solution to work with C++14 onwards, look into `std::shuffle` though. If, for some reason, those don't work, look into [the Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

If setting up the array is a once-off operation (i.e., you're not continuously changing elements and expecting the proportion of `-1` value to remain constant<sup>(1)</sup>), you can first just *not* populate the array with `-1` values at all, something like (pseudo-code):

```
for index in 0 .. array.size():
    value = -1
    while value == -1:
        value = yourRandomFunctionIncludingNegOne()
    array[index] = value
```

Then, you simply change a given number of them to `-1` after population:

```
for index in 0 .. array.size() / 5:  # 20%
    index = random(array.size())
    do:
        index = random(array.size())
    while array[index] == -1
    array[index] = -1
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> You can still *use* this method if the array is constantly changing, you just need to keep track of the `negative-one` and `other-than-negative-one` counts and adjust on the fly. It's a little more complicated but still doable.